# How to change offset of horizontal bars in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have used following graph config to render graph:

```
{
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    indexAxis: 'y',
    barThickness: 12,
    scales: {
      x: {
        suggestedMax: 6,
        suggestedMin: 0,
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawBorder: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 2,
          callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
            return value ? value + 'h' : value;
          },
        }
      },
      y: {
        type: 'category',
        grid: {
          drawBorder: false,
          borderDash: [4, 3],
          color: "#C2C8CD",
          drawTicks: false,
          offset: false,
        },
        ticks: {
        }
      }
    }
```

What I'm getting using above configuration.
[image: I'm getting this graph]

what I want:

[image: what I want]

Kindly help to render this graph using `react-chartjs-2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is to have the grid lines pass just under
each bar, that is not a standard feature, since the grid lines
pass either through the middle of the bar (with `offset: false`)
or through the middle of the space between bars.

You can use `chartjs-plugin-annotation` to draw annotation lines
instead of grid lines; short of that I can think of two ways to do that:
one using a trick, the other hacky.

**The trick** is to add an empty dataset after your actual dataset. That
will allocate an empty space on y axis for a bar of this dataset under
each of the real bars. You'll also have to make some adjustments: set
`options.scales.y.ticks.align` to `'end'` (or set a matching value
for `options.scales.y.ticks.labelOffset`, see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes))
to correctly align the tick labels; disable (filter out) the legend entry
for the phantom dataset; adjust the `y` position of the `x` scale.

Here's a set of options doing that - I used comments to remove wrong or
superfluous options from your post:

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Awake", "Deep", "Light", "Rem"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'data',
                backgroundColor: ['orange', 'green', 'lightBlue', 'black'],
                data: [3*6/100, 6*6/100, 76*6/100, 15*6/100]
            },
            {} // empty "phantom" dataset
        ]
    },
    options: {
        //type: 'horizontalBar', // no such thing, also type: not here
        indexAxis: 'y',
        barThickness: 16,
        scales: {
            x: {
                suggestedMax: 6,
                suggestedMin: 0,
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                    //drawBorder: false, // this is border.display
                },
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 2,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        return value ? value + 'h' : value;
                    },
                    maxRotation: 0
                },
                position:{ // set the x axis position below the last line
                    y: ({scale: {chart}}) => chart.scales.y.max
                }
            },
            y: {
                //type: 'category', // default
                grid: {
                    //drawBorder: false,  // this is border.display
                    //borderDash: [4, 3], // this is under border.dash
                    color: "#C2C8CD",
                    drawTicks: false,
                    offset: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    align: 'end'
                },
                border:{
                    display: true,
                    dash: [4, 3]
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
                labels: { // if display enabled, filter out empty dataset
                    filter(item){
                        return !!item.text;
                    }
                }
            },
            datalabels:{
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    const sum = context.dataset.data.reduce((s, x) => s + x);
                    return Math.round(value/sum*100).toFixed(1).replace(/\.?0+$/, '') + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
});
```

```html
<div style="max-width:400px; height: 200px">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```

**The hacky** solution would be based on a plugin that moves the
bars so they are on top of the grid line; that move can be done
in the `beforeDatasetDraw` hook, but care should be taken such that
each bar is moved moved only once, while the `beforeDatasetDraw` handler
might be called several times.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Awake", "Deep", "Light", "Rem"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'data',
                backgroundColor: ['orange', 'green', 'lightBlue', 'black'],
                data: [3*6/100, 6*6/100, 76*6/100, 15*6/100]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        barThickness: 16,

        clip: false, // allow the for the bar to overflow to the padding
        scales: {
            x: {
                suggestedMax: 6,
                suggestedMin: 0,
                grid: {
                    display: false,
                    drawBorder: false, // this is border.display
                },
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 2,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        return value ? value + 'h' : value;
                    },
                    maxRotation: 0
                },
                position:{ // set the x axis position below the last line
                    y: ({scale: {chart}}) => chart.scales.y.max
                }
            },
            y: {
                grid: {
                    color: "#C2C8CD",
                    drawTicks: false,
                    offset: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    //align: 'end', OR:
                    labelOffset: function({scale}){
                        const chart = scale.chart;
                        return -chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].height/2 ||
                            (scale.getPixelForValue(0) - scale.getPixelForValue(1/3));
                    },
                },
                border:{
                    display: false,
                    dash: [4, 3]
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    const sum = context.dataset.data.reduce((s, x) => s + x);
                    return Math.round(value/sum*100).toFixed(1).replace(/\.?0+$/, '') + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        ChartDataLabels,
        {
            beforeDatasetDraw(_, {meta}){
                if(meta.$shifted || meta.type !== 'bar' || !meta.data[0]?.height){ 
                    // shift bars only once, on bars only and after height has been computed
                    // assumes there's no initial animation on barWidth.
                    return;
                }
                meta.data.forEach(
                    (elem) => {elem.y -= elem.height/2;}
                );
                meta.$shifted = true;
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

```html
<div style="max-width:400px; height: 200px">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
```